# I get error - Use of undeclared type 'BaseCell' - while trying to create a Cell file in Swift following a tutorial

Tags: swift, cell, uicollectionviewcell, collectionview

I am a new programmer (self taught) and am following a youtube tutorial ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PNmuTTd5zWc&t=21s ) to learn how to program a UICollectionView that appears bottom up for my app.

When I try to create the file for the BaseCell in minute 4:50, I don't get the error.

> Use of undeclared type 'BaseCell'

[This is what it's supposed to look like according to the tutorial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDMIr.png)

Am I getting this error because it doesn't exist in Swift anymore or what might be a possible error?

Could someone help me out?

Comment: Do not post pictures of code or errors. Please post text as text, not as pictures.

Comment: `BaseCell` must be a class you created (or need to create) in your project. It's not something provided by iOS.

Comment: You may note that 5 seconds more into the tutorial (after the introduction of `SettingCell`) the author will explain that `BaseCell` is a custom class defined in `VideoCell.swift`. See the tutorial at 4:45.

Comment: Hi dfri I rewatched it again, thanks for the comment, I didn't quite understand that. So that means that for me to access the BaseCell, which they created in other tutorials, I need to also create the VideoCell.swift? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

the base cell class is a custom class of type UIcollection view cell

```
class BaseCell: UICollectionViewCell
{
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setUpView()
    }

    func setUpView()
    {

    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init (coder:) has been implemented")
    }
}
```

if you get the error Use of undeclared type 'BaseCell' then build your project again it will work.